# How to hide MIN(date) "aggregate" from SELECT row in the query output...SQL Server 2008

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server, mindate

I know you can remove a column to hide it but what about an aggregate or function?

```
SELECT MIN([date])AS FIRSTDAY,lastName,firstName,birthdate,gender
FROM [Day] d
GROUP BY lastName,firstName,birthdate,gender
```

Comment: Why do you want to hide it?

Comment: The end user does not want to see it on the report

Comment: I see. I use SSRS for my reports so this isnt an issue. Have u seen my  answer below?

Comment: Yes I just did, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CTE. It much easier to add more logic, like `ORDER BY` or `WHERE`

```
WITH MinDate AS
(
     SELECT MIN([date])AS FIRSTDAY, lastName,firstName,birthdate,gender
     FROM [Day] 
     GROUP BY lastName,firstName,birthdate,gender
)
SELECT lastName,firstName,birthdate,gender
FROM MinDate
-- WHERE
-- ORDER BY
```

If you just want to remove duplicate by lastName,firstName,birthdate,gender, use sub query when date is not duplicated value. By this, you can separate duplication removal logic from presentation.

```
SELECT D1.lastName, D1.firstName, D1.birthdate, D1.gender, -- More fields
FROM [Day] D1
WHERE D1.date = (
    SELECT MIN(D2.date) AS MinDate
    FROM D2 
    WHERE CHECKSUM(D1.lastName, D1.firstName, D1.birthdate, D1.gender) 
        = CHECKSUM(D2.lastName, D2.firstName, D2.birthdate, D2.gender)
)
```

It's your choice.

Answer (score 2):

With a sub query!

```
SELECT x.LastName,
       x.firstName,
       x.birthdate,
       x.gender
FROM (SELECT MIN([date])AS FIRSTDAY,lastName,firstName,birthdate,gender
      FROM [Day] d
      GROUP BY lastName,firstName,birthdate,gender) AS x
```